# clips.exe missing in destination folder after installing

Tags: installation, clips

After I install clips on my machine, there is no clips.exe file in destination folder where I have installed it. I can't do anything without it since I need to add it to PATH variable, right? This is how my folder looks after installation

[image: 1]

Am I supposed to do anything else besides installing, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run CLIPSDOS.exe if you want to interact with CLIPS using a simple terminal interface and run CLIPSIDE.exe if you want to run the integrated development environment. When you install CLIPS, shortcuts to these app will be placed in your start menu.